# jquery ajax in php to stop reload page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

When I clicked on book link he reloads the page and sorts the column.
Do I want to stop the reload using ajax,,, How?

this is my functions to this process.

this getBook function

```
public function getBooks($start = 0, $limit = 2, $order = "ASC")
{
   $sql_start = $start * $limit;
   $sql_limit = $limit;
   $sql_order_by = $order;

   $query = "SELECT Library.nameOfBook, userBook.book_id, userBook.user_id FROM loginUser JOIN userBook JOIN Library ON userBook.user_id = loginUser.id AND userBook.book_id = Library.id WHERE loginUser.username=:username ORDER BY Library.nameOfBook $sql_order_by LIMIT $sql_start, $sql_limit";
   $statment = $this->db->prepare($query);
   $statment->execute([
       ':username' => $this->username
   ]);
   $result = $statment->fetchAll();

  echo "<table id='myTable' border='1'>

  <tr>
   <th><a id='sorter' href='#'>Books</a></th>
   <th>Action</th>
   </tr>";
   foreach($result as $row){
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['nameOfBook'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" ."<input type='submit' id='delete".$row['book_id']."-".$row['user_id']."' onclick='deleteBook(this)' name='delete' value='Delete'>" . "</td>";
       echo "</tr>";
    }

   echo "</table>";
   echo "";
   return count($result);
 }
```

this jquery function

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $( "#sorter" ).click(function() {
    var order_by_value = $('input[name="order_by"]').val();
    if(order_by_value == "ASC"){
        $('input[name="order_by"]').val("DESC");
    }
    else {
        $('input[name="order_by"]').val("ASC");
    }
    $('input[name="current"]').trigger('click');
 });

 });
</script>
```

Comment: `$("#sorter").click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); ...`

Comment: its still refresh the page

Comment: Because you  click `$('input[name="current"]')` which is a submit button too I assume

Comment: so how i can fix this problem ? @mplungjan

Comment: Change all buttons to type="button" and ajax everything

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $( "#sorter" ).click(function() {
    var order_by_value = $('input[name="order_by"]').val();

$.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'the url link ',
                data: {
                    'order_by_value': order_by_value         
       },
                success: function (res) {
                    if(res == "ASC"){
                          $('input[name="order_by"]').val("ASC");
                     }
                    else {
                          $('input[name="order_by"]').val("DSC");
                         }
                    $('input[name="current"]').trigger('click');
                 });
                }
        });

</script>
```

Comment: No i didn't .. i asked ajax code to solve this problem, i don't say this is ajax code.

Comment: your code looks fine, can you give us more detail? error details?

Comment: I want stop refresh page  when i clicked on link book to order my book

Comment: Click is going to trigger event which in turn will probably reload your page, Like I said before if you can post your code it will be easier for us to help you

Comment: i past my function that getbook in table please check update code

Comment: are you able to go inside " $( "#sorter" ).click(function() {  "  ?... if not can  you try this  <a href="#" onclick="fn()">click here</a>

Comment: my code is work 100% ,,, but my problem like i said I want stop refresh page when i clicked on link book ,, so i must using ajax but in my case i don't how i can use it.

Comment: Okay, so try like this...

Comment: what the url put in  url:  in my situation?

Comment: i put the url  where the getBook function inside it ... and its not work .. now didn't do sort :/

Comment: URL in your case is the link where you will send your data

Comment: can i send it to UUser.php ?

Comment: and why he didn't do ascending when he become descending ??

Comment: when i change if(res == "ASC"){ to if(order_by_value == "ASC"){ its work but still refresh the page -_-

Comment: `$("#sorter").click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); ...`

Comment: yes you can sent it to user.php, learn the syntax....

use preventDefault like +mplunghab said.

In AJAX all the things that you have after success is in 'res' parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, never reload your page before you are sure that the ajax has completed its process.

Secondly, if you want to sort using JS run that code after you finish submitting the form or data in your case.

Here is how your ajax code with page reload on compeletion will look like

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'your_page_link.php',//this will be url of your backend page
                data: {
                    'name':name
                    'email':email            
                },// if you are using form then just use .serialize() to submit the form instead of preparing data like this use $("#form_id").serialize()
                success: function (msg) {
                    resp = msg;
                }
        }).done(function(){
             if(resp == your_expected_response){
              window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
             }else{
              //your error handler
             }
        });
```

Hope this will be helpful, please feel free to ask if any clarification is required..

Cheers!!